# LevelList in contour plots

Tags: matlab

There is some information I couldn't find neither in the documentation nor in forums:

- My Z has 5 orders of magnitude, how can I plot correctly these values? 0.002 all the way to 100-ish
- Is it possible to specify this order of magnitude rather than the exact number? In LevelList somehow, I mean. E.g. I want a level at 10^2, which can mean 100 or 190, or 131.34.

Code:

```
[C,h] = contour(beta,alpha,Coupling)

clabel(C,h)

axis([0 3 0 3])
```

Comment: *which can mean 100 or 190, or 131.34*-> But how would you choose one or the other? Does your data has genuinely only 5 unique values? If that is the case, why use contour at all and not e.g. `imagesc`?

Comment: Yeah, this slightly changes the definition of contour plot. All values are different, but, in general, they are within 5 orders of magnitude

Comment: Of course it changes the contour plot, the values are different. But why one or the other? Wha tis the criteria?

Comment: The order of magnitude only. Those three values would be the same level. Also, I noticed that, by default, contour() doesn't "explore" the range of given values. Do you know any advanced tutorial to this function? I find the mathworks one pretty basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you had some random data

```
%    Data     Order of magnitude base 10
a = [0.0964   % O(1e-1)
     0.0157   % O(1e-2)
     0.0970   % O(1e-1)
     0.9571   % O(1e+0)
     0.4853   % O(1e+0) 
     0.8002   % O(1e+0)
     1.4188   % O(1e+0) 
     4.2176   % O(1e+1)
     9.1573]  % O(1e+1)
```

Where the orders of magnitude are given by

```
orders = round(log10(a));
```

You can replace your `z` values with this formula `z2 = 10.^round(log10(z))` to define them by their magnitude. Then produce a contour plot with the distinct orders of magnitude just as you did before, but using `z2` not `z`.

---

**For your example:**

```
CouplingMagnitudes = 10.^(round(log10(Coupling)));
[C,h] = contour(beta, alpha, CouplingMagnitudes)
```